# Android Activity to Fragment: Replacing "this" with getActivity() throws error: ClassCastException

Tags: android, kotlin

I tried to make a Todo-App following a tutorial. The app worked. But now I want to expand the tutorial and convert the MainActivity to a fragment, that is called in the MainActivity(ToDoActivity). I read that a fragment has no context and so the context of the MainActivity should be used. So I changed `this` to `getActivity()` in the Fragment.

The context is handed over to the TaskAdapter class which is a custom BaseAdapter(). The TaskAdapter creates a TaskRowListener interface out of the context. This worked with activity, but converted to a fragment it throws an error "ToDoActivity" cannot be cast to "TaskAdapter$TaskRowListener"

The error occurs in the fragment here:
`_adapter = TaskAdapter(getActivity(), _taskList!!)`

and here in the adapter:
`var _rowListener: TaskRowListener = context as TaskRowListener`

If I print `this` in the original code the result is:
`com.Info_DH.sgru_rchr.UniversityGoesAgile.ToDoActivity@cbaaca4`

If I print `getActivity()` in the converted fragment the result is:                         `com.Info_DH.sgru_rchr.UniversityGoesAgile.ToDoActivity@8aa307d`

So I am even more confused why it does not work.
I would really appreciate it if someone knew what the problem could be.

Main (ToDoActivity):

```
class ToDoActivity : FragmentActivity() {



     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_test)



        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.canvas, Todofragment.newInstance(), "Test")
                .commit()
        }
```

Fragment:

```
class Todofragment : Fragment(), TaskRowListener {

    var _taskList: MutableList<Task>? = null

    lateinit var _adapter: TaskAdapter

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        _taskList = mutableListOf<Task>()

        _adapter = TaskAdapter(getActivity(), _taskList!!)

..............

}
```

TaskAdapter:

```
class TaskAdapter(context: Context, taskList: MutableList<Task>) : BaseAdapter() {

    private val _inflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
    private var _taskList = taskList
     var _rowListener: TaskRowListener = context as TaskRowListener

.........
}
```

TaskRowListener:

```
interface TaskRowListener {

    fun onTaskChange(objectId: String, isDone: Boolean)
    fun onTaskDelete(objectId: String)
    fun onTaskEdit(objectId: String, taskDesc:String)

}
```

Log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.Info_DH.sgru_rchr.UniversityGoesAgile, PID: 14117
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Info_DH.sgru_rchr.UniversityGoesAgile/com.Info_DH.sgru_rchr.UniversityGoesAgile.ToDoActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.Info_DH.sgru_rchr.UniversityGoesAgile.ToDoActivity cannot be cast to com.Info_DH.sgru_rchr.UniversityGoesAgile.TaskAdapter$TaskRowListener
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.Info_DH.sgru_rchr.UniversityGoesAgile.ToDoActivity cannot be cast to com.Info_DH.sgru_rchr.UniversityGoesAgile.TaskAdapter$TaskRowListener
        at com.Info_DH.sgru_rchr.UniversityGoesAgile.TaskAdapter.<init>(TaskAdapter.kt:19)
        at com.Info_DH.sgru_rchr.UniversityGoesAgile.Todofragment.onCreate(Todofragment.kt:89)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2339)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1377)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1109)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments(FragmentTransition.java:996)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:99)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2364)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2229)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3221)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3171)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:192)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:560)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1248)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6679)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2609)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Comment: The activity doesn't implement TaskRowListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're expecting `TaskRowListener` inside your `TaskAdapter` class:

```
class TaskAdapter(context: Context, taskList: MutableList<Task>) : BaseAdapter() {

    ..
     // here you're expecting a TaskRowListener
     var _rowListener: TaskRowListener = context as TaskRowListener

.........
}
```

but you're activity isn't a `TaskRowListener`. So, you need to modify your activity to implement `TaskRowListener` with something like this:

```
class ToDoActivity : FragmentActivity(), TaskRowListener {
  ...
}
```

Although I think that you should not use activity at all to keep the Adapter handled only by the `TodoFragment` and keep using:

```
_adapter = TaskAdapter(this, _taskList!!)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Modifying the Class was the solution. Now it works. I will try to handle the Adapter with the Fragment only, but at the moment I´m just happy that it doesn´t crash anymore.

Comment: @Sebi: Great that you solve the problem! You can close this question by marking this answer as an accepted answer. ;)